# execute updateconfiguration destroy activity

Tags: android

I have use statement `updateconfiguration(skin)` in my app.the question is when the statement execute it will destory and rebuild activity instance in where it is .

How to avoid destroy and rebuild activity?

Comment: call activity.finish() it solve your problem

Comment: @sunil thanks for your answer i'm trying it